# Create button to collapse header (javascript)

Tags: javascript

This is my site: http://www.glovesboxing.co.nz/
You will see at the top there is a header that collapses once you have scrolled 50px down the page, and expands again when you scroll back up.

I would like to make it so that instead of expanding when you scroll up, there is a toggle button on the header to expand/collapse it. (I also still want it to collapse after the initial scrolling 50px like it does now)

I assume this is simple, but I don't know javascript well enough to get the mark-up correct.

This is my current script (this question applies to the "header" element - the "sidebar" and "right-content" are just in there to adjust their top margins as the header expands/collapses so they move with the header) :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).on("scroll",function(){
        if($(document).scrollTop()>50){ 
            $("header").removeClass("large").addClass("small");
            $(".sidebar").removeClass("large").addClass("small");
            $(".right-content").removeClass("large").addClass("small");
            }
        else{
            $("header").removeClass("small").addClass("large");
            $(".sidebar").removeClass("small").addClass("large");
            $(".right-content").removeClass("small").addClass("large");
            }
        });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Simple Example

You can use the code for checking if a `checkbox` is `selected` or not.

Try adding an `else if` logic for expanding the **HEADER**.

`else if(headerToggle.prop('checked')==false){`

The above will get a bit messy though. Your best bet is writing a new function as well to fail-safe it and ensure that your scroll function doesn't break it, which will also make it collapse-able if they so desire:

```
$(document).on("scroll",function(){
    var headerToggle = $('#headerToggle');
    if($(document).scrollTop()>50){ 
        $("#header").removeClass("large").addClass("small");
    }
    else if($(document).scrollTop()<=50){
        $("#header").removeClass("small").addClass("large");
    }
});
$('#headerToggle').on('click', function() {
    $('#header').toggleClass('small');
    $('#header').toggleClass('large');
});
```

**I can't really provide more guidance without more code from you. There are many ways to solve this.**

Comment: Thanks this worked perfectly, except I wanted the menu to not expand again when you scroll back up, but that is easy enough to edit by changing the else if statement.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this, maybe?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        var top = $(window).scrollTop();
        if (top > 50) {
            $('header').css({
                'height': '20px',
                'width': '20px',
                'overflow': 'hidden',
                '-webkit-transition': 'all .5s ease',
                '-moz-transition': 'all .5s ease',
                'transition': 'all .5s ease'
            });
            $('.menu a').fadeIn(500);
            $('header').addClass('min');
        } else {
            $('header').css({
                'height': '',
                'width': '',
                'overflow': '',
                '-webkit-transition': 'all .5s ease',
                '-moz-transition': 'all .5s ease',
                'transition': 'all .5s ease'
                }).removeClass('min');
            $('.menu a').fadeOut(500);
        }
    });

    $('.menu a').click(function(){
        if ($('header').hasClass('min')) {
            $('header').css({
                'height': '',
                'width': '',
                'overflow': ''
             }).removeClass('min');
        } else {
            $('header').css({
                'height': '20px',
                'width': '20px',
                'overflow': 'hidden',
                '-webkit-transition': 'all .5s ease',
                '-moz-transition': 'all .5s ease',
                'transition': 'all .5s ease'
            }).addClass('min');
        }

    });
});
```

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/unnhJ/1/

If this is what you're after, the code can be pared down by storing the repeated bits in variables/objects.